# Discrepancy in distributing limits over addition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

It has been stated in my book that

> $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(f+g)(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$
> If both $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) $ exist.

Now similar distributive property has been stated to be true for multiplying two functions, and dividing them as well.

Now lets consider

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{100}{x^{100}-1}-\frac{50}{x^{50}-1}$$

Now by the above stated property, I can consider $f(x)=\frac{100}{x^{100}-1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{50}{x^{50}-1}$, and hence evaluate the limit becomes $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{100}{x^{100}-1}-\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{50}{x^{50}-1}$$ Recalling the formula $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$, I can manipulate the limit to get $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{100(x-1)}{(x-1)(x^{100}-1)}-\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{50(x-1)}{(x-1)(x^{50}-1)}$$$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{100}{100(x-1)}-\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{50}{50(x-1)}$$$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{(x-1)}-\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{(x-1)}$$

Now since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(f+g)(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$, we can say that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}(f+g)(x)$.

So the limit becomes $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}$$$$=0$$ ...which is wrong and I know it. I have solved the limit by adding them and cancelling terms out, but my question is where is the fallacy in my application of the property stated?

Another case which I can remember right now out of many, where I saw such a problem arise is in solving $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(x-x^2\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)\right)$, where I had to use Taylor expansion of the logarithmic term to solve the limit but just distributing the limit over the entire function gave $0$.

Comment: The property you want requires that the limits exist separately, which they don't.  Also, I can't follow the manipulations you performed.

Comment: @lulu I added a line to explain the manipulation which I have performed

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{100}{x^{100}-1}$ doesn't exist, so you can't split the limit.